# what is the fastest way to increment a slice of a list?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
lst = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to increment all numbers above index 4.

```
for i in range(4,len(lst)):
    lst[i]+=2
```

Since this operation needs to be done many time, I want to do it the most efficient way possible.
How can I do this fast.

Comment: It depends on what the list is being used for, what is reading the updated list?

Comment: Consider `numpy`. (Or C extensions, though in this simple case, I doubt you'll see an improvement.)

Comment: the list is updated 1000s of times before it becomes a column in a dataframe

Comment: This sounds like a better use-case for numpy

Comment: That depends on the exact operation to perform. Can you share more details?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) for fast array manipulations, check the example below:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

# add 2 at all indices from 4 till the end of the array
lst[4:] += 2

print(lst)
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: Equivalent - `np.add(a[4:],2,a[4:])`.

Comment: @wwii functionally equivalent, but for large lists (e.g. 10,000 elements) over many iterations (I looked at 1,000,000), it consistently performs marginally worse.

Comment: @Grismar - I get a two percent swing, sometimes one is faster sometimes the other is faster. Using a previously defined slice object, `slice(4:,None)`, speeds both up a smidge.

Answer (score 4):

If you are updating large ranges of a large list many times, use a more suitable data structure so that the updates don't take O(*n*) time each.

One such data structure is a [segment tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html#toc-tgt-9), where each list element corresponds to a leaf node in a tree; the true value of the list element can be represented as the sum of the values on the path between the leaf node and the root node. This way, adding a number to a single internal node is effectively like adding it to all of the list elements represented by that subtree.

The data structure supports get/set operations by index in O(log *n*) time, and add-in-range operations also in O(log *n*) time. The solution below uses a binary tree, implemented using a list of length <= 2n.

```py
class RangeAddList:
    def __init__(self, vals):
        # list length
        self._n = len(vals)
        # smallest power of 2 >= list length
        self._m = 1 << (self._n - 1).bit_length()
        # list representing binary tree; leaf nodes offset by _m
        self._vals = [0]*self._m + vals

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, list(self))

    def __len__(self):
        return self._n

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self._n):
            yield self[i]

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i not in range(self._n):
            raise IndexError()

        # add up values from leaf to root node
        t = 0
        i += self._m
        while i > 0:
            t += self._vals[i]
            i >>= 1
        return t + self._vals[0]

    def __setitem__(self, i, x):
        # add difference (new value - old value)
        self._vals[self._m + i] += x - self[i]

    def add_in_range(self, i, j, x):
        if i not in range(self._n + 1) or j not in range(self._n + 1):
            raise IndexError()

        # add at internal nodes spanning range(i, j)
        i += self._m
        j += self._m
        while i < j:
            if i & 1:
                self._vals[i] += x
                i += 1
            if j & 1:
                j -= 1
                self._vals[j] += x
            i >>= 1
            j >>= 1
```

Example:

```py
>>> r = RangeAddList([0] * 10)
>>> r.add_in_range(0, 4, 10)
>>> r.add_in_range(6, 9, 20)
>>> r.add_in_range(3, 7, 100)
>>> r
RangeAddList([10, 10, 10, 110, 100, 100, 120, 20, 20, 0])
```

It turns out that NumPy is so well-optimized, you need to go up to lists of length 50,000 or so before the segment tree catches up. The segment tree is still only about twice as fast as NumPy's O(*n*) range updates for lists of length 100,000 on my machine. You may want to benchmark with your own data to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fast way of doing it:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
new_list = [*lst[:4], *[x+2 for x in lst1[4:]]]
# or even better
new_list[4:] = [x+2 for x in lst1[4:]]
```

In terms of speed, numpy isn't faster for lists this small:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
npa = np.array(lst)


def numpy_it():
    global npa
    npa[4:] += 2


def python_it():
    global lst1
    lst1 = [*lst1[:4], *[x+2 for x in lst1[4:]]]


print(timeit.timeit(numpy_it))
print(timeit.timeit(python_it))
```

For me gets:

```
1.7008036
0.6737076000000002
```

But for anything serious numpy beats generating a new list for the slice that needs replacing, which beats regenerating the entire list (which beats in-place replacement with a loop like in your example):

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

lst1 = list(range(0, 10000))
npa = np.array(lst1)
lst2 = list(range(0, 10000))
lst3 = list(range(0, 10000))


def numpy_it():
    global npa
    npa[4:] += 2


def python_it():
    global lst1
    lst1 = [*lst1[:4], *[x+2 for x in lst1[4:]]]


def python_it_slice():
    global lst2
    lst2[4:] = [x+2 for x in lst2[4:]]


def python_inplace():
    global lst3
    for i in range(4, len(lst3)):
        lst3[i] = lst3[i] + 2


n = 10000
print(timeit.timeit(numpy_it, number=n))
print(timeit.timeit(python_it_slice, number=n))
print(timeit.timeit(python_it, number=n))
print(timeit.timeit(python_inplace, number=n))
```

Results:

```
0.057994199999999996
4.3747423
4.5193105000000005
9.949074000000001
```

Comment: This creates a new list every time

Comment: @IainShelvington and then gets rid of the old and still outperforms the operation that was suggested as an alternative - but feel free to suggest an improvement. I agree that an in-place solution might be faster.

Comment: Time it with 500000 entries instead of 8, you'll like it.

Comment: Numpy will outperform here if you are using large arrays. Size 8 is probably not a relevant test case

Comment: @Grismar `lst[4:] = [x+2 for x in lst[4:]]` would be slightly faster

Comment: I test with 17537553 length list and this code gives me `0.0009360313415527344` time, while Numpy give me `1.0594840049743652`

Comment: The real answer here is: use tools like `timeit()` and experiment with different solutions - but typically rely on libraries for bulk.

Answer (score 2):

Use assign to slice:

```
lst[4:] = [x+2 for x in lst[4:]]
```

Test (on my ancient ThinkPad i3-3110, Python 3.5.2):

```
import timeit
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

def python_it():
    global lst
    lst = [*lst[:4], *[x+2 for x in lst[4:]]]

def python_it2():
    global lst
    lst[4:] = [x+2 for x in lst[4:]]


print(timeit.timeit(python_it))
print(timeit.timeit(python_it2))
```

Prints:

```
1.2732834180060308
0.9285018060181756
```

Answer (score 1):

use python builtin [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function and lambda

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst[4:] = map(lambda x:x+2, lst[4:])

print(lst)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Or `lst[4:] = map(2 .__add__, lst[4:])`.